how to connect two module with app-routing.module.ts in angular
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:3:72 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "input"
3     
~~~~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:4:9 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "br"
4     
~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:5:68 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "input"
5     
~~~~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:6:9 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "br"
6     
~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
solve this problem "Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:3:72 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "input"
3     
~~~~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:4:9 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "br"
4     
~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:5:68 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "input"
5     
~~~~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
ERROR
src/app/user/user.component.html:6:9 - error NG5002: Void elements do not have end tags "br"
6     
~~~~~
src/app/user/user.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './user.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
" ?
